# Learning VF development in 2021..would it help?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, visualforce

Is learning VF development in 2021 still worth it? With aura and LWC in place especially the LWCs greatly supporting "anybody can code"? Would learning VF development be beneficial in 2021?
Thoughts?

Comment: I don't believe so. I haven't had to do VF for years now and avoid any company that is still using it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the job you have, or the job you want. Most new customers won't use Visualforce (most likely), but there are many, *many* thousands of jobs at companies that have orgs that are 5-10-15+ years old with a large number of Visualforce and other "legacy" code.

For example, we have hundreds of Visualforce pages (most that generate PDFs) that will take significant time to convert to an Apex-based solution. Apex-based PDF generation is still a bit annoying, as you have to query the records, generate the HTML, etc. Visualforce is still probably the easiest way to generate PDFs in most cases, anyways.

I would say that Visualforce will still remain viable for a number of years in the future. You need not be an *expert* at it, but you should still be casually knowledgeable about what Visualforce can and can't do, and basic syntax. Just going through the [Visualforce Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) modules should give you everything you need to know for most use cases, and it's less than 3 hours of time invested.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I do have a basic overview of VF pages.. but in my 3.5 years of exp. I have used VF only to override the detail page buttons/ Embedding aura into it or rendering pages as PDF. Was just wondering if I need to know deep intricacies and dive deep into classic VF development.

Comment: @MayankSareen As I kind of implied, no, you don't need a deep dive in most cases. Just don't be surprised if you end up with a project that actually does need this kind of expertise.